# How reset gnome-fallback settings to defaults?

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic, gnome-tweak-tool

On Ubuntu 16.04 and using gnome-fallback, I have messed the settings with `gnome-tweak-tool`. 
I'm wondering if there is a way to return the configs to default?

If it is not possible, I'd like to know what are these parameters as Default:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/06/reset-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-18-04/) article, I found the answer which is pretty simple:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```